# Origin of "Котлин"

Tags: этимология

I searching for "kotlin" word definition, probably someone who knows Russiancan help me.

What does 'Kotlin' mean? 
It's related to Kotlin Island? What the history behind this island and the name kotlin?

Comment: You can read about it in russian version of wiki https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Котлин

Comment: @KhirgiyMikhail wikipedia is a very helpful but not always a 100% reliable source. Also, it's  mentioned in Russian wiki but there's no word in English one - and since the author does not Russian it won't help him a lot.

Comment: Kotlin (Language) is named by Kotlin Island not far for St.Petesburg, Russia (JetBrains core team hometown)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Deriving `Котлин` from `котёл` is an example of folk etymology - and actually, it's completely wrong. To start with even if it was derived from котёл - in Russian it would hardly end up as Kotlin - it's just that `-lin` ending is not typical at all. It's way, way too germanic.

Actually, there's a trade agreement between Novgorod Republic and Hanseatic League dated back to XIIIth century - and the island Kotlin is mentioned their under the name "Ketlingen". You can find more information about that particular document [here](https://eu.spb.ru/images/centres/respub/novgorodica/Skvairs_Novgorodica.pdf).

Ironically it still [can](http://world.lib.ru/k/kolibaba_s_n/top90.shtml) be related to "котёл" (but it's still very suspicious, and even if it is - the XVIIIth century myth is still an anecdote):

> На старинных шведcких картах, хранящихся в архивах Стокгольма, остров
>   надписан как Kettusaari - фин. 'лисий остров'. В договоре великого
>   князя Ярослава с немецкими и голландскими послами, 1207 г., название
>   записано в переосмысленной форме Ketlingen (ниж.-нем. Kettel 'котел',
>   -ingen сложный формант, употребительный в нем. названиях селений). В Новгородских грамотах XIII в. Котлинг, позже о. Котлин.

Roughly, Finnish people called this island `Keettusaari`, then (probably through Swedish) this end up as `Ketlingen` in Dutch and German sources and was borrowed by Novgorod Republic as `Котлинг` (Kotling) which evolved to just `Kotlin`.

And yes, programming language was called Kotlin as a reference to both Kotlin being island near Saint Petersburg and the language itself being a competitor to Java - which is also named after an island.

Comment: Does jetbrains have offices on the island?

Comment: @ycomp: Most likely that not. Internet search returns only 2 offices in St. Petersburg, and an office on Kotlin would not be the most convenient. Long drive from the center of city, and not much infrastructure around yet. But Kronshtadt is a worth to visit [tourist destination](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g2394587-Activities-Kronshtadt_Kronshtadtsky_District_St_Petersburg_Northwestern_District.html).

Comment: @ycomp There is an office on an island, but on another one: Vasilyevsky Island, not Kotlin ;).

Comment: _"To start with even if it was derived from котёл - in Russian it would hardly end up as Kotlin"_. Fun fact: There is actually a pretty big island in Russia, whose name is derived exactly from котёл: [Остров Котельный](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)